# Variable test value after post event

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I m trying to test a variable after a post event (the method function exist in spring server side ) in javascript file . Normally according to this value i will decide to send a notifcation to the other users or not .
First i check if the number of the order exist or not , if exist i will not send a notification for the users if not exist i save the order and sent a notification for users that there is a new order submitted by and end user.
This my javascript code :

```js
    $('#btn-save').on('click', function (e) {
 var test = document.getElementById("error").value ;
 console.log("test =", test);
   
    if (test == "test1") {
     
     console.log("test1 =", test);

    toastr.options = {
       "closeButton": true,
       "debug": false,
       "newestOnTop": false,
       "progressBar": false,
       "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
       "preventDuplicates": false,
       "onclick": null,
       "showDuration": "3300",
       "hideDuration": "1000",
       "timeOut": "0",
       "extendedTimeOut": "0",
       "showEasing": "swing",
       "hideEasing": "linear",
       "showMethod": "fadeIn",
       "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
    }
   
     
    toastr["error"]("error !!!!");

     
   } else {
     
    console.log("test =", test);
      sendForm();
    
       
   }
 
});
```

I pass the variable test from the spring controller method like below :

```js
 String test = "test";


@PostMapping("/saveordre")
 public String formOrdre(Model model, @Validated OrdreAjout ordre1, @Validated OrdreSupp ordre2, String typeOrdre,
   BindingResult bindingresult, @RequestParam("num_ord") String num_ord, Notif_A2 not_a2,
   @RequestParam("Fichier1") MultipartFile file) {
   String test_error = null;
  String p = "0";
  if (ordreRepository.findByNum(num_ord) != null) {

    test = "test1";
     test_error ="test1";
    String size2 = null;
    List<Notif_A2> notilist = noti_a2.listNotifA2();
    long size = notilist.stream().count();
    size2 = Long.toString(size);
    model.addAttribute("size2", size2);
    model.addAttribute("listnoti", notilist);

    String size3 = null;
    List<Notif_A3> notlist = noti_a3.listNotifA3();
    long size1 = notlist.stream().count();
    size3 = Long.toString(size1);
    model.addAttribute("size3", size3);
    model.addAttribute("note", notlist);
    
    
    model.addAttribute("error4", test);

   model.addAttribute("error3", test_error);
   model.addAttribute("ordre", new Ordre());
   return "/formordre";

  }

  else {
    test = "test";
    model.addAttribute("error4", test);

   String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

   try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get(UPLOADED, filename), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    try {
     Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    
    }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
    model.addAttribute("error1", e);
   
    return "FormOrdre";
    
   }

   try {
    if (typeOrdre.equals("OA")) {
     ordreMetier.save(ordre1);
     not_a2.setOrdre(ordre1);
     not_a2.setFlag_stat_a2("0");
     not_a2.setFlag_stat_a3("0");
     not_a2.setTyp_noti("add");
     noti_a2.save(not_a2);
    }

    else {
     ordreMetier.save(ordre2);
     not_a2.setOrdre(ordre2);
     not_a2.setFlag_stat_a2("0");
     not_a2.setFlag_stat_a3("0");
     not_a2.setTyp_noti("add");
     noti_a2.save(not_a2);
    }
            
    

    
    
    
    
   }

   catch (Exception e) {
  
    model.addAttribute("error", e);
    return "FormOrdre";
    

   }

  
   
   String test2 = "test2";
   model.addAttribute("success", test2);
   model.addAttribute("ordre", new Ordre());
   
   return "/formordre";
   
  }
```

this code does not work very well , it sent notification when the order number exist which not correct and does not sent notifcation when the order does not exist.Anyone had an idea how to resolve it !!!!!

Comment: Debug the code by first checking that the service is returning. What is the value of `console.log("test =", test);`

Comment: Does not appear in the console developer tool of the browser

Comment: Are you sure the click event is getting fired? write a log before the ` document.getElementById("error").value` probably the element does not exist and giving a error. Does the console show any error?

Comment: i m using sockjs and stomp js for the notifcation maybe this is the reason why doesnot appear in the console the value of test . There is no error in the post event .

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in jquery library , just try this link if you doesn't added 
before

But if you added check your code place if you put it under the line copy it to above of this link .

Example  :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
.....
</script>
```

if your code like this retry to copy the link below like to be like this :

```
<script>
.....
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are used this link ? to get jquery library  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js}"></script>